# How to know the ControlType of a UI Element from CurrentControlType property

Tags: c#, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

Basically I am using UIAutomationClient.Interop.dll for some UI work I am currently doing and I am facing the following issue:

- I have a UI Element I would like to know its Control Type.
- UIAutomationClient.Interop.dll exposes the following property: ***IUIAutomationElement::CurrentControlType property***
- Above property returns an Int that represents the Control Type ID but not a ControlType object.

Question:

- How could I know what is the ControlType of an UI Element by just knowing its ID? I was not able to find out any other useful information.

**NOTE**:

I am using the UIAutomationTypes.dll to definte the ControlType object

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you use  UIAutomationClient.Interop instead of the standard UIAutomationClient ?

Answer (score 1):

I use `GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty)` in IronPython. Probably this is what you want. It should return ControlType object. Though I use its string representation `.ProgrammaticName.lstrip('ControlType.').strip("'")`.

Comment: I tried that out and I am getting an exception.

Basically what I did was:

var currentControlType = root.GetCurrentPropertyValue(root.CurrentControlType); It returned that the value does not fall withing the expected range.

Comment: Okay, it works different in C# and IronPython. There is C# code that works for me: `root.Current.ControlType.ProgrammaticName`. It returns string "ControlType.Pane". So `root.Current.ControlType` represents a ControlType object. It has `Id` property as well.

Comment: Maybe I am using a different DLL but I cannot call to root.Current.ControlType.ProgrammaticName.

The Interop DLL I am using allow me to do root.CurrentControlType that returns a string object and not a ControlType object. Where did you get your DLL from?

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\UIAutomationClient.dll`

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking how to do this in 2021 (with IUIAutomationElement).
You simply need to use the `LookupById()` function provided by the System.Windows.Automation.ControlType class.

```
// 
IUIAutomationElement element;
// ...
// your code to retrieve the element you want
// ...

// the next line fixes a bug in ControlType class, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13971182/991782
ControlType.Button.ToString();

var elementControlType = System.Windows.Automation.ControlType.LookupById(element.CurrentControlType);
```