# What is the ControlType in Accessibility Insights for Windows and how does it map to HTML elements?

Tags: accessibility-insights

Accessibility Insights for Windows shows the following property:

`ControlType    Group(50026)`

when I hover over a search box that is an `<input />` html tag.
I used Google Chrome `Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

How does AI4W determine the control type of the html tag?

The [accessibility insights doc](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/windows/getstarted/inspect) says the [control type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-supportinguiautocontroltypes) is a concept from the [Microsoft UI automation accessibility framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). You can look up the `50026` id for `Group` on [this reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-controltype-ids).

It is not yet clear to me how AI4W determined the exact control type. I suspect Chrome implements a [Client-Side (Proxy) UI Automation Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-clientsideprovider) but I am not sure about it. If it does, how does the implementation deduce the control types?

Related questions:

- [How to know the ControlType of a UI Element from CurrentControlType property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747375/how-to-know-the-controltype-of-a-ui-element-from-currentcontroltype-property)
- [Does Microsoft UI Automation Framework work with Chrome, Python and Java Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216824/does-microsoft-ui-automation-framework-work-with-chrome-python-and-java-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to [Rob Gallo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60512302/986533):

To determine the exact accessibility provider used by the browser:

1. Start Accessibility Insights for Windows.
2. Select `live inspect` and point to element of interest.
3. Set the tool to always show following properties: `FrameworkId` and `ProviderDescription` (use the cogwheel in upper right of pane containing the `Properties` table).
4. Observe the value.

For example, this:

```
FrameworkId: Chrome 
ProviderDescription: [pid:33748,providerId:0x0 Main(parent link):Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (IAccessible2) (unmanaged:UIAutomationCore.DLL)]
```

means that UIA is translating to its format the data exposed by Chrome as `IAccessible2`, as explained in [UI Automation: An Incomplete Guide for UI builders – Part 1](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ui-automation-incomplete-guide-builders-part-1-guy-barker/). There are more possible UIA providers **even when using the same browser**. Knowing the right UIA provider is required for root causing problems with the UIA hierarchy. See the linked article for details.

In addition, the `HTML Accessibility API Mappings 1.0` spec section on [accessibility APIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aam-1.0/#intro_aapi) links to [UI Automation for W3C Accessible Rich Internet Applications Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-ariaspecification) which explains specified `ControlTypes` for given ARIA roles, which are defined in [this spec (v1.1)](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/).

A good article providing additional context for this discussion: https://sarahmhigley.com/writing/roles-and-relationships/

Answer (score 2):

As described on this [Chrome accessibility page](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/accessibility), Chrome exposes HTML and [ARIA](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/aria/) control types/roles through an accessibility API called [IAccessible2](https://accessibility.linuxfoundation.org/a11yspecs/ia2/docs/html/).

As of Windows 10.0.1903, Windows translates IAccessible2 into UIA. I was unable to find any documentation which specifically describes the mapping of IAccessible and IAccessible2 roles to UIA control types, but it is probably very close to [the mapping recommended by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/core-aam-1.2/#mapping_role_table).

Accessibility Insights displays the UIA control type after Windows has converted the IAccessible2 data to UIA.